# Peculiarities in importing variable from module

Tags: python, module, global-variables

This is what I have in my tests.py file:

```
def func():
    global x
    x = 200
    return x

x = 100
```

Now I expect that whenever I'll issue

```
from tests import x
```

I will get `100`. But this is not the case.

```
>>> from tests import func
>>> from tests import x
>>> x
100
>>> func()
200
>>> x
100
>>> from tests import x
>>> x
200
```

What's the principle here? And why does it make sense to have it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules are global, and are only loaded **once** even if you have multiple `import` statements. Setting module globals stay global.

That's because `import` does **two** things:

- Load the module object if it doesn't exist yet in `sys.modules`
- Bind names (`import foo` binds the name `foo` to the module, etc.). How names are bound depends on the exact form of `import`:

  - `import foo` is essentially `foo = sys.modules['foo']`
  - `import foo as bar` is `bar = sys.modules['foo']`
  - `from foo import ham` is `ham = sys.modules['foo'].ham`
  - `from foo import ham as spam` is `spam = sys.modules['foo'].ham`

Repeated `import` statements only bind names again, as the module itself is already loaded.

So, using `from tests import x` assigns `x = tests.x`, creating a new variable name. Just like

```
foo = 100
bar = foo
foo = 200
```

will leave `bar` set to `100`, using `from tests import x` will not see `x` change when you then alter `tests.x` in the module.